# modernizr.loadd (yepnope) not loading file on iphone using 'touch' test

Tags: iphone, touch, modernizr, yepnope

I am trying to send additional css using modernizr.load (yepnope) to touch screen devices (e.g. iPhone). I know 'touch' doesnt neccessarily mean all devices but it will do for now.

This is the code I have:

```
Modernizr.load({
 test: Modernizr.touch,
 yep : '/css/touch.css'
});
```

However the css doesnt seem to load on my iPhone 3GS (IOS 4.1). The path is right as if I change the code to '`nope`' and test on my laptop the css loads fine.

Any ideas why the css isnt loading on my iphone?

Cheers,
Adi

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers lie about their touch capabilities. To check if your browser reports touch events, go to this page: http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html